# Unable to create project from archetype in Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

I am trying to create a simple Maven project in Eclipse Luna. As this is my first maven project so I am starting with a simple one. I am trying to crate a simple web project using the **webapp-j2ee14** archetype.

While creating I found that this archetype is not present in archetype list. So I tried with **Add Archetype** option and Provided the following archetype options.

```
<archetype>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes</groupId>
  <artifactId>webapp-j2ee14</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
  <repository>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/archetypes/webapp-j2ee14/1.3/</repository>
</archetype>
```

The above code snippet is basically from **archetype-catalog.xml** file in **.m2** directory in my system, but I actually entered them from eclipse UI.

Now, when I am clicking finish it's giving me the following error...

[image]

I tried with few other repo url after searching google but getting the same error. Where can I get the correct repo url for this archetype??

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5):

Add Remote Archetype in your eclipse it will show you that option. Following are the steps:

1. File--->New---> Maven Project---->Next--->Click on tab Configure
2. Separate window will open... Maven-->Archetypes-->Click on Add Remote Catalog--> In Catalog File type "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml" and click on Apply and then Ok
3. Now in new Maven Project select Remote Archetype from Catalog and you will find webapp-j2ee14 option there.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem and i was creating a simple Web App. I created the MAVEN project first then i deleted it and again when i created it i got this error. So i changed the version of archetype. I was using 2.16 version of the archetype that i was adding to my MAVEN project, changed it to latest 2.26 and it worked for me.
You can check the latest version from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/archetype-catalog.xml

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem as I have deleted a previously created project from Eclipse.
Later, I deleted the .metadata file and the project from workspace. Then this problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue, I have solved by manually removing unused **pom.xml** file  at the working workspace or root of workspace directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think the work space has messed up of some reason. These steps below may help

1. Close eclipse
2. delete the `.metadata` directory
3. Restart the eclipse, pointing to same workspace and try the process to create new maven project

or if this approach didn't work

1. switch to a fresh new workspace and try the same process to create your maven project

This is worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

After working whole day, finally I found the solution. I just went to Eclipse marketlace(help-Eclipse marketplace) and updated maven from there. Now it works wonders. Earlier I was unable to install TestNG plugin from Eclipse marketplace, but now after updating maven from there, Testng plugin successfully installed in my eclipse luna.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to create a **maven archetype quickstart** and faced this issue, I have never created any maven project before so for those below is the steps you need to follow -

1. Go to to **Run -> Run As -> Maven Install**
2. In the project explorer right click on **pom.xml file -> Maven -> Update project.**

This will for sure resolve the issue.

Eclipse version I am using : 2021-09 (4.21.0)